# callback function not executes unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function to execute a callback after the fade out animation of the textarea finishes:

```
function inputReset() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (lastExtend === true) {
      return resolve();
    };
    console.log('inside inputReset');
    const textarea = $("textarea").first();
    textarea.fadeOut(1500, "swing", async() => {
      console.log('inside callback');
      await textareaAnimeEnded(textarea);
      console.log('after await textareaAnimeEnded(textarea)');
      return resolve();
    });
  });

  function textareaAnimeEnded(textarea) {
    console.log('inside textareaAnimeEnded');
    inputClear();
    textarea.fadeIn(0);
    Dots.show();
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500));
  }
}
```

But unexpectedly I only see the  `console.log('inside inputReset');` and although the fade out animation occures but I never get to the callback function (we never reach `console.log('inside callback');`)

What I'm missing?

Comment: `textarea.fadeOut` -> what library are you using?

Comment: jQuery.........

Comment: I ask because it wasn't listed in the tags. Is it just jquery, or do you also use an animation plugin?

Comment: I think it's pure jQuery...

Comment: Does it actually find the textarea? `fadeOut` won't call the callback if the query returns no results.

Comment: jQuery is not going to be interested in the fact that your callback function is `async`. It will completely ignore the Promise returned.

Comment: jQuery doesn't need to do anything with the Promise for this to work.

Comment: Code runs fine when I add the missing method and variable What is different?

Comment: @Pointy I don't think so...come back to you with a simple codepen...

Comment: I can not replicate your issue https://codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/JjXqJMz --- I also tried in a stack snippet. Same result.

Comment: @backtick yes it does. When that `await` line is reached, the function will return (well, `yeild`). The code inside jQuery will not be `awaiting` that callback.

Comment: Also @SaraRee you did not post how that function (`inputReset()`) is wired up to anything else. How is it called? How is it registered as an animation completion handler?

Comment: Also note that a much simpler situation could be that `$("textarea").first()` is an empty jQuery object. You'd get no errors if that were the case, but nothing would happen.

Comment: Looks like this code works with jQuery v3.3.0 or later. With earlier versions, I see the behavior you describe.

Comment: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/JjXqJpV?editors=1111

Comment: @Pointy jQuery's job ends as soon as it calls the "complete" callback. It doesn't matter if the callback kicks off an async sequence of tasks. jQuery doesn't need to await the callback for it to work.

Comment: the above code is working fine:

Comment: @backtick but it's an `async` function. When that `await` line is encountered, the function will `yield`, and the remainder of the function will not be run unless something (the caller) *expects* it to be `async` and internally does a `.next()` to resume the function. Now, in this case, since the "missing in action" `console.log()` is *before* the `await`, I think it might be something a lot simpler. It would be good to add a `console.log()` to make sure `textarea` is not a zero-length jQuery object.

Comment: @Pointy the codepen above is working in the same situation...

Comment: @Pointy I think you're confusing promises with generators...? Async functions require absolutely _nothing_ of their callers. they return promises that encompass the total purpose of the function, that are guaranteed to either resolve or reject. There is no yielding and no `next` method

Comment: @backtick that's how `async/await` is implemented (internally)

Comment: @backtick no I need some coffee or something

Comment: Someone tell me why callback works for me if only I use it like `textarea.fadeOut(1500, "swing", foo);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion here is due to jQuery version mismatches. JQuery's `isFunction` check was updated in version 3.3.0 to accept async functions and generators.

`fadeOut` and other animation functions check the type of the callback argument. If it isn't a "function" (by jQuery's definition), then jQuery assumes no callback was passed.

The callback passed to `fadeOut` must therefore satisfy jQuery's definition of a function. And, unfortunately, before v3.3.0 that definition didn't include async functions or generators.

The check jQuery did before v3.3.0 was basically:

```
({}).toString.call(maybeFunction) === '[object Function]'
```

(actual algorithm [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.2.1/src/core.js#L453) and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.2.1/src/core.js#L269) and used [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.2.1/src/effects.js#L490) by `fadeOut` and all other animations)

We can see that async functions and generators don't pass this check:

```
({}).toString.call(() => {}) // '[object Function]'
({}).toString.call(async () => {}) // '[object AsyncFunction]'
({}).toString.call(function*() {}) // '[object GeneratorFunction]'
```

However, with the new check added in v3.3.0:

```
typeof maybeFunction === 'function'
```

all of these pass:

```
typeof (() => {}) // 'function'
typeof (async () => {}) // 'function'
typeof function*() {} // 'function'
```

This is why in versions < 3.3.0 you see the animation working, but your async callback function is not called. JQuery doesn't recognize it as a function. In fact, if you omit the `easing` parameter, jQuery tries to set the passed async callback function as the animation's easing, which breaks jQuery:

```
textarea.fadeOut(2000, async () => {})
// jquery.js:6515 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```

for more nitty gritty details, read on:

---

The changelog in question is [here](https://blog.jquery.com/2018/01/19/jquery-3-3-0-a-fragrant-bouquet-of-deprecations-and-is-that-a-new-feature/):

> Update isFunction to handle unusual-@@toStringTag input

The jQuery PR responsible for this change is [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/3617):

> Generators and async functions are still functions, and we can recognize them with typeof

Most notably [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/3617/files#diff-7eb52b366866677666470e019283c8eaL215):

```
return jQuery.type( obj ) === "function"
```

got changed to (simplified):

```
return typeof obj === "function"
```

Comment: This is Really great answer but I'm using `jquery-3.5.0.min`

Comment: And yes If I don't use an async function as the callback function every thing works fine...

Comment: @SaraRee are you able to reproduce it in a codepen? The one you posted doesn't reproduce it in jQuery v3.5.0. As of v3.3.0, jQuery should not distinguish between async and non-async functions. P.S. you can log `$.fn.jquery` to see the jQuery version actually being used. I've had situations where multiple versions of jQuery were being loaded on a page by accident.